# Не работает анимация клика по карточке, сделанной на figure

Tags: css

Есть карточка сделана на figure, и если на нее нажать на android, анимация работает, а если на ios, то не работает в чем может быть проблема?

```
<figure class="snip1543">
 <img src="img/boiler-gas.jpg" alt="колонка не зажигается">
  <figcaption>
   <h3>Газовая колонка не зажигается</h3>
    <p>Батарейки вышли из строя.</p>
   </figcaption>
  </figure>


.snip1543 {
background-color: #fff;
color: #000;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
width: 400px!important;
height: 300px!important;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0)
}

.snip1543 *,
.snip1543 *:before,
.snip1543 *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-transition: all .45s ease;
-o-transition: all .45s ease;
transition: all .45s ease
}

.snip1543 img {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
width: 450px!important;
height: 300px!important;
vertical-align: top
}

.snip1543:before,
.snip1543:after {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
content: '';
background-color: #ff3c00;
opacity: .5;
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=50)";
-webkit-transition: all .45s ease;
-o-transition: all .45s ease;
transition: all .45s ease
}

.snip1543:before {
-webkit-transform: skew(30deg) translateX(-80%);
-ms-transform: skew(30deg) translateX(-80%);
transform: skew(30deg) translateX(-80%)
}

.snip1543:after {
-webkit-transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(-70%);
-ms-transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(-70%);
transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(-70%)
}

.snip1543 figcaption {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 1;
bottom: 0;
padding: 25px 40% 25px 20px
}

.snip1543 figcaption:before,
.snip1543 figcaption:after {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: #ff3c00;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
content: '';
opacity: .5;
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=50)";
z-index: -1
}

.snip1543 figcaption:before {
-webkit-transform: skew(30deg) translateX(-100%);
-ms-transform: skew(30deg) translateX(-100%);
transform: skew(30deg) translateX(-100%)
}

.snip1543 figcaption:after {
-webkit-transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(-90%);
-ms-transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(-90%);
transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(-90%)
}

.snip1543 h3,
.snip1543 p {
margin: 0;
opacity: 0;
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
letter-spacing: 1px
}

.snip1543 h3 {
font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: 100;
line-height: 1em;
text-transform: none;
opacity: 1;
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=100)";
padding-bottom: 10px
}

.snip1543 p {
font-size: 18px;
padding-bottom: 15px
}

.snip1543 a {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 1
}

 .snip1543:hover h3,
 .snip1543.hover h3,
 .snip1543:hover p,
 .snip1543.hover p {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0);
-ms-transform: translateY(0);
transform: translateY(0);
opacity: .9;
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=90)";
-webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
-o-transition-delay: .2s;
transition-delay: .2s
}

.snip1543:hover:before,
.snip1543.hover:before {
-webkit-transform: skew(30deg) translateX(-20%);
-ms-transform: skew(30deg) translateX(-20%);
transform: skew(30deg) translateX(-20%);
-webkit-transition-delay: .05s;
-o-transition-delay: .05s;
transition-delay: .05s
}

.snip1543:hover:after,
.snip1543.hover:after {
-webkit-transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(-10%);
-ms-transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(-10%);
transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(-10%)
}

.snip1543:hover figcaption:before,
.snip1543.hover figcaption:before {
-webkit-transform: skew(30deg) translateX(-40%);
-ms-transform: skew(30deg) translateX(-40%);
transform: skew(30deg) translateX(-40%);
-webkit-transition-delay: .15s;
-o-transition-delay: .15s;
transition-delay: .15s
}

.snip1543:hover figcaption:after,
.snip1543.hover figcaption:after {
-webkit-transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(-30%);
-ms-transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(-30%);
transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(-30%);
-webkit-transition-delay: .1s;
-o-transition-delay: .1s;
transition-delay: .1s
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Старые версии iOS Safari поддерживают только свойства и значения с вендорным префиксом.

Используйте `-webkit-transition: -webkit-skew` вместо `-webkit-transition: skew`. И т.п.